# Is a good practice to use postDelayed for delay the opening of fragment?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I'm making an app based on TMDB database. I have a recyclerView loaded with the newest tv shows. When I click in a poster, I call the TMDB api, get an object with the show info and open a fragment loaded with that object data.

The thing is when I go back and click in other tv show, when the fragment is opened again it briefly shows the info of the previous tv show I clicked.

I think the problem is that I'm using livedata to pass the data between the viewmodel and the fragment and it's loading the data already in the livedata.
So i'm using this to delay a little the opening of the fragment:

HomeFragment - OnCLick

```kotlin
viewmodel.getShowDetails(showId)

val mHandler = Handler()
val monitor = Runnable {
   Navigation.findNavController(view)
             .navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeToShowDetail())
}

mHandler.postDelayed(monitor, 300)
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
  private var showMutable = MutableLiveData<ShowDetails>()

    fun getShowData(id: Int) {
        TmdbRepository.getDetails(id) // This returns an RxJava Observable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .subscribe {
                showMutable.postValue(it)
            }
    }


    fun getShow(): LiveData<ShowDetails> {
        return showMutable
    }
```

ShowDetailFragment

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
     viewModel.getShow().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            mShow = it
            setData(mShow) // this fills the textviews, images, etc
     })
}
```

Is it good to use this method? Or maybe I should use something else to pass data between the fragment and the viewmodel instead of the livedata?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not good to use **postDelayed**.

As your ViewModel is shared, you MutuableLiveData will hold the data if the previous Movie Details.

Solving this problem could have 2 forms:

**First Solution**, Use StateUi, includes **Loading**, **Success**, **Failure** as follow:

```
sealed class StateUi {
    data class Success(val data: Any) : StateUi()
    object Loading : StateUi()
    class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : StateUi()
}
```

also, add StateUi.Loading in doOnSubscribe() as follow:

```
TmdbRepository.getDetails(id) // This returns an RxJava Observable
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .doOnSubscribe(StateUi.Loading)
        .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
        .subscribe {
            showMutable.postValue(it)
        }
```

Make your MutuableLiveData as follow

```
private var showMutable = MutableLiveData<StateUi<ShowDetails>>()
```

and observe in your Fragment, how this would solve your problem?

Because you are observing to state, So by default the state of MutuableLiveData will be Loading, not hold data of the previous movie.

**Second Solution**,
create separate ViewModel class for each fragment. But I do recommend the first solution.

Comment: Yes, but it's only to pass an Integer (the show id) for the API call. But if I make the call before opening the fragment, I don't really need it. Can I use an alternative for livedata?

Comment: I guess maybe something wrong with your data observing, could you share your fragments and viewModel code?

Comment: I edited the question with some code, hope is useful

Comment: Do you have a viewModel for HomeFragment and another for DetailsFragment? or they are shared?

Comment: it is shared yes

Comment: I've edited my answer, includes the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but Android Studio throws a couple of errors when adding your code:

In .doOnSubscribe(StateUi.Loading):   
Type mismatch. 
Required: 
Consumer<in Disposable!>! 
Found: 
StateUi.Loading 

In private var showMutable = MutableLiveData<StateUi<ShowDetails>>():  
No type arguments expected for class StateUi